# Request to undelete answer to question "Windows Azure target machine actively refused connection when using emulator"

Tags: support, status-completed, undelete-request

I have answered ["Windows Azure target machine actively refused connection when using emulator"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16364781/753737) on Azure Caching in a rather unruly manner and a moderator deleted it. I've taken the time to improve it by adding more information about my proposed solution and linking to alternative solutions I've found while I was having the same problem.

I would kindly ask a moderator to undelete it (I can't vote for undeletion and I am unsure about flagging it). If it isn't possible, can I have an explanation of what was wrong about my answer so I can improve?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Flag it for moderation attention and ask the moderators to review your updates and undelete the answer.

Comment: @Yannis thanks for your prompt reply, I've flagged my answer as you suggested.

Comment: Why didn't you flag it as a duplicate if the original answer was an answer to another SO question?

Comment: @Bart thanks for pointing out the question, I haven't found it my search. However I think that this question is not a mere duplicate, since I'm asking an explanation about what could be wrong about my answer.

Comment: @edymtt Seems that has been resolved now as well with the answer below. ;) Great edit to your answer by the way.

Comment: @casperOne If I understand your question correctly, the question was not a duplicate (the error message was different), but the solution was the same. As the moderators noticed, my answer was not of high quality.

Comment: @Bart thanks for your interest and your appreciation of my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, your answer should be self-contained, even if it's a link to a different answer. This applies to any link-only answers, not just those with external links.

Your answer looks much, much better now, so I've undeleted it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation -- I'll take into consideration for my next answers.